# Access/manipulate the issue view from custom UI | I want to trigger the issue description input to be focused from my app

Tags: atlassian-forge

I have a button in my custom ui application using the issue-panel module and I want that when it is clicked the description input of the current issue should be focused and the user can automatically start typing.

I have read through https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/how-to-get-the-dom-in-forge/50725 and it is clear that there is no way to do it by manipulating the DOM but is there a native way to achieve this or something similar?